# React Native Line chart animation

Tags: react-native, npm, charts, linechart

Is there any way to build this kind of behavior in react native (any chart library)
here I attached a sample gif file[image]

Comment: May be you can check [react-native-animated-charts](https://github.com/rainbow-me/react-native-animated-charts). It might not have full features you need, but at least you can take reference from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this line chart module of react native svg charts. Do let me know if this helps :)

[rn-svg-chart](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts#linechart)

Answer (score 0):

Try [react-native-gifted-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-charts)

The above chart can be easily created using this library.
Here's a very similar chart explained in the library's [official documentation about pointerConfig](https://gifted-charts.web.app/areachart#pointerConfig).[image: chart-example-gif]